# CSS Style not being applied in AngularJS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Got a slightly baffling situation.  We have an angular controller that is properly feeding data to the page.  There will always be an unknown number of columns so we went with this approach to render the table:

```
<table border="1" ng-repeat="table in xc.tables">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 150px !important" ng-class="{'missingpeoplefirstcolumn': $first}" ng-repeat="column in table.cols">{{column}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in table.rows">
        <td style="width: 150px !important" ng-class="{ 'pinkify': {{row[column]}} == 0 , 'grayit': $last}" 
            ng-repeat="column in table.cols">
                {{row[column]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the only CSS being applied on the page:

```
.pinkify
{
    background-color: pink;
    color: pink !important;
}

.grayit{
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: black !important;
}

.missingpeoplefirstcolumn
{
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

'Pinkify' and 'grayit' are being applied, as expected.  However, we're trying to force the width on the first column to be 150px and it doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't matter if the width is in the stylesheet or inline.  Does anyone have an idea what's wrong and how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
ng-class="{'missingpeoplefirstcolumn': $first}"
```

To this

```
ng-class="{'missingpeoplefirstcolumn': first}" // remove the $ before 'first'
```